# Creating a pseudo color plot with a linear and nonlinear axis and computing values based on the center of grid values

Tags: python, plot

I have the equation: z(x,y)=1+x^(2/3)y^(-3/4)

I would like to calculate values of z for x=[0,100] and y=[10^1,10^4]. I will do this for 100 points in each axis direction. My grid, then, will be 100x100 points. In the x-direction I want the points spaced linearly. In the y-direction I want the points space logarithmically.

Were I to need these values I could easily go through the following:

```py
x=np.linspace(0,100,100)
y=np.logspace(1,4,100)
z=np.zeros( (len(x), len(y)) )

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        z[i,j]=1+x[i]**(2/3)*y[j]**(-3/4)
```

The problem for me comes with visualizing these results. I know that I would need to create a grid of points. I feel my options are to create a meshgrid with the values and then use pcolor.

My issue here is that the values at the center of the block do not coincide with the calculated values. In the x-direction I could fix this by shifting the x-vector by half of dx (the step between successive values). I'm not so sure how I would do this for the y-axis. Furthermore, If I wanted to compute values for each of the y-direction values, including the end points, they would not all show up.

In the final visualization I would like to have the y-axis as a log scale and the x axis as a linear scale. I would also like the tick marks to fall in the center of the cells, correlating with the correct value. Can someone point me to the correct plotting functions for this. I have to resolve the issue using pcolor or pcolormesh.

Should you require more details, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean with "values at the center of the block do not coincide with the calculated values"? Do you want one value per block such that the center of block `0`, for example, is in `(x[0], y[0])`, of block `1` is in `(x[1], y[1])`,...?

Comment: What code are you using to create the visualization? What result do you get, and why is that result wrong? What should it look like instead? We can only help with problems that are clearly explained, in code that is actually shown to us.

Comment: Thanks you for the clarifying questions. @Breno, I will attempt to make this more clear. More importantly, thank you for addressing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In current `matplotlib`, you can use `pcolormesh` with `shading='nearest'`, and it will center the blocks with the values:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_plot = np.log10(y)
z[5, 5] = 0  # to make it more evident
plt.pcolormesh(x, y_plot, z, shading="nearest")
plt.colorbar()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_yticks(y_plot)
plt.axvline(x[5])
plt.axhline(y_plot[5])
```

Output:
[image: Result]